# How to change a control's text font color programmatically into a custom color

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button control. I'd like to change it's text's font color into a custom color that I want which is #33CCFF, programmatically.

My current code is

```
Button1.ForeColor = Color.#33CCFF;
```

I have also tried

```
Button1.ForeColor = #33CCFF;
```

Both didnt work..

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Are you using WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, windows Phone, Metro, ASP.NET...?

Comment: I'm doing this for an ASP.NET website..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use:

```
Button1.ForeColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#33CCFF");
```

For reference: [ColorConverter on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.colorconverter.aspx)

Alternatively you can use `ColorTranslator`:

```
Button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#33CCFF");
```

Comment: There is no reason that `ColorConverter` is not available in ASP.Net, as soon as you reference `System.Drawing.dll`

Answer (score 0):

```
Button1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0x0033CCFF);
```

Reference : [Color.FromArgb Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFF00");
```

where you can use an RGB hexadecimal code.